# Break a String Buffer into 80-character Chunk

Tags: java, string

I want to create an array of string out of a StringBuffer. I need to break the buffer in every 80 characters. So first string element in the array will contain first 80 characters from the buffer, second element will contain the next 80 characters from the buffer. The buffer size may not be divisible by 80. So, the last string element of the array may have the rest which can be less than or equal to 80 characters.

What would be the best way to do that considering that substring function of String might get an index out of bounds exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just make sure you don't ask for too much:

```
String[] splitBuffer(StringBuffer input, int maxLength)
{
    int elements = (input.length() + maxLength - 1) / maxLength;
    String[] ret = new String[elements];
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        int start = i * maxLength;
        ret[i] = input.substring(start, Math.min(input.length(),
                                                 start + maxLength));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

You may want to consider returning a `List<String>` instead of a `String[]`, as they're often more convenient to work with.

Comment: @Milli: Yes, I think so... I originally had it as Math.max, but fixed it pretty quickly.

Comment: Both Min and Max break in some points. I tried using Math.min(input.length() - start, start + maxLength)..still no luck. It breaks in the center of the loop, breaks at 3 if the total loop is 6 or so.

Comment: By the way, my buffer was 960-character long. My maxLength was 80. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @Milli: Ah, had forgotten to add start... Substring works differently in .NET and Java. Have a look now I've added start to both arguments.

Comment: Thanks Jon. This works like a charm. Also thanks for the algo. It was cleaver.

Answer (score 3):

Or do it the regex way:

```
public static String[] splitBuffer(CharSequence input, int maxLength) {
    return input.toString().split("(?<=\\G.{" + maxLength + "})");
}
```

**Explanation:** `\G` is a placeholder for the last match

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use the [getChars(int, int, char[], int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringUtils.substring(String str, int start, int end)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substring%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) instead of the normal String substring method. This method will never throw an exception.